# Notification not appearing Notification Tray

Tags: android, notifications

In my application I have a `LocationTester Service implements LocationListener` which is responsible for retrieving the Reminders from sqlite Db and comparing their distances with current location in `onLocationChanged()` method and then present the information if the distance is less than 1km and then throw notification related to that particular reminder.

The problem is that when I check for a certain location with a successful response every thing goes well even the toast is displaying where it meets the condition but I am not getting any sort of notification.

LocationTester Service:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        dataSrc.open();
        ArrayList<Reminders> rems = (ArrayList<Reminders>) dataSrc.findALL();

        for(Reminders x:rems){
            Location locs = new Location("");
            locs.setLatitude(x.getLat());
            locs.setLongitude(x.getLng());

            double dis = location.distanceTo(locs);
            if(dis<=1000){
                String title = x.getTitle();
                String des = x.getDescription();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityShowReminders.class);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle(title);
                builder.setContentText(des);
                noteManag = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                noteManag.notify(noteId,builder.build());
                noteId += 1;
                Toast.makeText(this, title+"("+des+")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

datasrc:

```
public List<Reminders> findALL(){
        List<Reminders> reminder = new ArrayList<Reminders>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(ReminderDBOpenHelper.TABLE_REMINDER, allColumns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,cursor.getCount()+" rows");
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                Reminders reminders = new Reminders();
                reminders.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
                reminders.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE)));
                reminders.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
                reminders.setLat(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LAT)));
                reminders.setLng(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONG)));
                reminder.add(reminders);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.remindericon);`the notification will not appear without this. 
And for `illegalargumentexception contentintent required notifiction` try attaching pending intent.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,YourTargetClass.class );
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                }
```

Comment: thanks bro, I've used it but now my app is getting n exception illegalargumentexception contentintent required notifiction how to deal with it.

Comment: try attaching pending intent with it. I think you are targeting version below honey comb. going to edit my answer. check it

Answer (score 0):

Use this for generate notification

```
    static int uniqueID = 0 ;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText("text");
    builder.setTicker("Ticker");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 1500});
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    uniqueID = uniqueID + 1;
    notificationManager.notify(uniqueID, notification);
```